# How can I convert an axis-angle representation to a Euler angle representation

Tags: rotations

This is a CAD problem but it boils down to just maths I think.

I have a sphere that I need to rotate, and the program I use needs me to give the rotation about 3 fixed axes. This would be easy if I happened to want to rotate about one of those axes, but I don't.

To achieve this, I need a function to transform the axis-angle representation to a Euler angle representation.

The offsets of the axis of rotation from the co-ordinate axes are: -17°, +40° and -30°

The application has symbols like the following next to the angles:

[image]

I've found [this](http://www.euclideanspace.com/maths/geometry/rotations/conversions/angleToEuler/) titled "Conversion Axis-Angle to Euler", which looks like what I need, but I'm not sure about the terminology. Do 'heading', 'attitude' and 'bank' relate to the offsets above, and 'angle' to the angle of the desired rotation about the axis?

Comment: First move your fixed axis to one of the coordinate axes, then perform your rotation, then move your fixed axis back to its original location.

Comment: @Neal the package I'm using is not true 3D software and can't do that unfortunately. It does allow me to feed in new offsets and animate in that fashion…

Comment: The key terms I think you're missing are *axis-angle* and *Euler angle* representations. There doesn't seem to be an existing question about the conversion from axis-angle to Euler angles, but knowing the terminology is a good starting point when searching.

Comment: @Peter many thanks I've had a go at updating the question with those terms

Comment: I am confused by the negative angles. I was expecting angles between the axis of rotation and the coordinate axes; like distances from Chicago, Los Angeles, and New York. What is the significance of the negative angles?

Comment: @robjohn I guess -17 is just equivalent to +163? The diagram in the application has graphics that I'll add to the question…

Comment: You can rotate around each of the $x$, $y$, and $z$ axes in the software, and what you want is to rotate about the axis you've given. Is that correct?

Comment: @robjohn yes, that's right, how do I transform a rotation of, say, 2° about my axis into three rotations about the 'Euler' axes (if that's the correct use of the term)?

Comment: [This Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_formalisms_in_three_dimensions) has a lot of conversion formulae.

Comment: @Rahul thanks, that's interesting, though a bit above my head!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the following, we adjust $\delta$ in the range specified by $(2)$, $\sigma_B=\pm1$, and $\sigma_C=\pm1$ until we get the required rotation.

**Angles $\alpha$, $\beta$, and $\gamma$**

Let $\alpha$, $\beta$, and $\gamma$ be the angles from the $X$, $Y$, and $Z$ axes to the axis of rotation, $A$. These three angles are related by the [Pythagorean Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pythagorean_theorem):
$$
\cos^2(\alpha)+\cos^2(\beta)+\cos^2(\gamma)=1\tag{1}
$$
These angles, along with the angle $\delta$, will be assumed to be in the range $[0,\pi]$.

---

**Angles $\rho_X$, $\rho_Y$, and $\rho_Z$**

Consider the diagram on the sphere

$\hspace{3.2cm}$[image]

For each value of $\delta$ so that
$$
\sin^2(\delta)\ge\max\left(\cos^2(\alpha),\cos^2(\gamma)\right)\tag{2}
$$
the circle of radius $\delta$ about $Y$ intersects both the circle of radius $\alpha$ about $X$ and the circle of radius $\gamma$ about $Z$ at one or two points.

Using the [Spherical Law of Cosines](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spherical_law_of_cosines), we can compute
$$
\angle AXY=2\tan^{-1}\left(\frac{\cos(\gamma)}{\sin(\alpha)+\cos(\beta)}\right)\tag{3}
$$
For each $\alpha$ and $\delta$, there are one or two solutions for $B$. To account for this, let $\sigma_B=\pm1$. Then
$$
\begin{align}
\rho_X&=\angle AXY-\sigma_B\cos^{-1}\left(\frac{\cos(\delta)}{\sin(\alpha)}\right)\tag{4}\\
\angle YBX&=\pi-\sigma_B\cos^{-1}(\cot(\alpha)\cot(\delta))\tag{5}\\
\angle XYB&=\sigma_B\cos^{-1}\left(\frac{\cos(\alpha)}{\sin(\delta)}\right)\tag{6}
\end{align}
$$
Using the Spherical Law of Cosines, we can compute
$$
\angle YZA=2\tan^{-1}\left(\frac{\cos(\alpha)}{\sin(\gamma)+\cos(\beta)}\right)\tag{7}
$$
For each $\gamma$ and $\delta$, there are one or two solutions for $C$. To account for this, let $\sigma_C=\pm1$. Then
$$
\begin{align}
\rho_Z&=\angle YZA-\sigma_C\cos^{-1}\left(\frac{\cos(\delta)}{\sin(\gamma)}\right)\tag{8}\\
\angle ZCY&=\pi-\sigma_C\cos^{-1}(\cot(\gamma)\cot(\delta))\tag{9}\\
\angle CYZ&=\sigma_C\cos^{-1}\left(\frac{\cos(\gamma)}{\sin(\delta)}\right)\tag{10}
\end{align}
$$
For consistency, define $\sigma_A=\mathrm{sgn}(\cos(\beta))$. Since $\angle XYZ=\frac\pi2$,
$$
\begin{align}
\rho_Y&=\frac\pi2-\angle XYB-\angle CYZ\tag{11}\\
\angle XAZ&=\pi-\sigma_A\cos^{-1}(\cot(\alpha)\cot(\gamma))\tag{12}
\end{align}
$$

---

**Angle of Rotation**

The rotations $\rho_X$, $\rho_Y$, and $\rho_Z$ computed above will fix the axis $A$. Accounting for [parallel transport](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parallel_transport), the rotation about the axis $A$ is equal to the total geodesic curvature
$$
\rho_X\cos(\alpha)+\rho_Y\cos(\delta)+\rho_Z\cos(\gamma)\tag{13}
$$
minus the area of the light red deltoid region (since it is traversed clockwise).

Using [Girard's Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spherical_trigonometry#Area_and_spherical_excess), the areas of the purple triangles are
$$
\begin{align}
|\triangle A|&=\angle ZXA+\angle AZX+\angle XAZ-\pi\\
|\triangle B|&=\angle BXY+\angle XYB+\angle YBX-\pi\\
|\triangle C|&=\angle YZC+\angle CYZ+\angle ZCY-\pi
\end{align}\tag{14}
$$
The areas of the white sectors are
$$
\begin{align}
|\unicode{x2AA6} X|&=\rho_X\,(1-\cos(\alpha))\\
|\unicode{x2AA6} Y|&=\rho_Y\,(1-\cos(\delta))\\
|\unicode{x2AA6} Z|&=\rho_Z\,(1-\cos(\gamma))
\end{align}\tag{15}
$$
The area of the light red deltoid is
$$
\frac\pi2-|\triangle A|-|\triangle B|-|\triangle C|-|\unicode{x2AA6} X|-|\unicode{x2AA6} Y|-|\unicode{x2AA6} Z|\tag{16}
$$
Note that depending on the signs of $\sigma_B$ and $\sigma_C$, the light red deltoid may have one or two lunes attached.

Subtracting $(16)$ from $(13)$ yields a rotation of
$$
|\triangle A|+|\triangle B|+|\triangle C|+\rho_X+\rho_Y+\rho_Z-\frac\pi2\tag{17}
$$
Four applications of Girard's Theorem reduces $(17)$ to
$$
\angle XBY+\angle YCZ+\angle ZAX-2\pi\tag{18}
$$

---

**Example:**

Suppose $\alpha=\gamma=\frac\pi3$ and $\beta=\frac\pi4$. Note that $\cos^2(\alpha)+\cos^2(\beta)+\cos^2(\gamma)=1$.

By $(2)$, we can choose any $\delta$ so that $\sin^2(\delta)\ge\frac14$. Let $\delta=\frac\pi6$.

$(3)$: $\angle AXY=0.615479708670388$

$(4)$: $\rho_X=0.615479708670388$

$(5)$: $\angle YBX=\pi$

$(6)$: $\angle XYB=0$

$(7)$: $\angle YZA=0.615479708670388$

$(8)$: $\rho_Z=0.615479708670388$

$(9)$: $\angle ZCY=\pi$

$(10)$: $\angle CYZ=0$

$(11)$: $\rho_Y=\frac\pi2$

$(12)$: $\angle XAZ=1.91063323624902$

$(18)$ says that the rotation is $1.91063323624902$.

---

Note that the angles specified in your question do not satisfy $(1)$:
$$
\cos^2(\alpha)+\cos^2(\beta)+\cos^2(\gamma)=2.25134287511099\ne1
$$
There is no point that is $-17^\circ$, $+40^\circ$, and $-30^\circ$ from the coordinate axes.

Comment: I really appreciate this answer: from your last statement it looks like I'm misinterpreting the symbols representing the three variables

Comment: @JackDouglas: Perhaps those numbers represent rotations on the coordinate axes?

Comment: That certainly seems to fit the diagram now I look again, thanks

Comment: @JackDouglas: I think my second answer should cover that case.

Answer (score 0):

Since your angles do not work with the original interpretation, let's assume that they represent the angle of rotation on each axis. That is, the rotation is given by
$$
\hspace{-8mm}
A=\begin{bmatrix}
\cos(\gamma)&\sin(\gamma)&0\\
-\sin(\gamma)&\cos(\gamma)&0\\
0&0&1
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
\cos(\beta)&0&-\sin(\beta)\\
0&1&0\\
\sin(\beta)&0&\cos(\beta)
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
1&0&0\\
0&\cos(\alpha)&\sin(\alpha)\\
0&-\sin(\alpha)&\cos(\alpha)\\
\end{bmatrix}\tag{1}
$$
I think the easiest way to find the axis for such a rotation is to use the formula I give in [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/520412) to find the axis of rotation, $v$, for a rotation matrix, $A$.

Let $u$ be any column of $A^T-I$. We can find the cosine of the angle of rotation by
$$
\cos(\theta)=\frac{u\cdot Au}{|u|^2}\tag{2}
$$
The sine of the angle of rotation is given by
$$
\sin(\theta)=\pm\frac{v\cdot u\times Au}{|v||u|^2}\tag{3}
$$
The sign used in $(3)$ is dependent on the definition of the cross product and on the orientation of the coordinate axes.

---

Example:

For $\alpha=-17^\circ$, $\beta=40^\circ$, $\gamma=-30^\circ$, $(1)$ yields
$$
A=\begin{bmatrix}
 0.663413948168938 & -0.640907051572032 & -0.386160697922698 \\
 0.383022221559489 & 0.734217757814514 & -0.560551747746327 \\
 0.642787609686539 & 0.223969719728075 & 0.732571944233734
\end{bmatrix}
$$
Using the first formula from the cited answer, we get that the axis of rotation is
$$
v=\begin{bmatrix}
0.256626911763841\\
-0.336582028018252\\
0.334940238250282
\end{bmatrix}
$$
Let $u$ be the first column of $A^T-I$:
$$
u=\begin{bmatrix}
-0.336586051831062\\
-0.640907051572032\\
-0.386160697922698
\end{bmatrix}
$$
$(2)$ says $\cos(\theta)=0.565101825108593$ and $(3)$ gives $\sin(\theta)=0.825021167764159$.

Therefore, $\theta=0.970239657223180=55.59^\circ$.

Comment: forgive my slowness, does this enable me to compute the 'angle of rotation on each [Euler] axis' given an angle of rotation about the axis of rotation?

Comment: The other answer allows you to compute the rotations on the three coordinate axes to make a given rotation on a given axis. This answer allows you to compute the axis and the rotation on that axis given the rotations on the coordinate axes. This is what I thought you were asking for.

Comment: OK, sorry for the confusion!