# Converting from Euler angles to axis-angle and back

Tags: rotations

I've been writing a small utility library for converting different 3D rotation representations. My sources are mainly Wikipedia, a couple text books, and [Martin Baker's excellent site](http://www.euclideanspace.com/maths/geometry/rotations/conversions/index.htm). I've been unit testing each of my conversions (using values verified with MATLAB), and the only ones that don't hold up are the Euler angles to axis-angle conversion and the inverse of that. Using Martin Baker's [conventions](http://www.euclideanspace.com/maths/standards/index.htm) of `bank=Rx`, `heading=Ry`, and `attitude=Rz`, I'm unable to achieve the correct output.

I'm using his equations from [here](http://www.euclideanspace.com/maths/geometry/rotations/conversions/angleToEuler/index.htm) for axis-angle to Euler, and [here](http://www.euclideanspace.com/maths/geometry/rotations/conversions/eulerToAngle/index.htm) for Euler to axis-angle, but they are not matching my sample cases. I'm thinking it may be confusion over ordering.

**Given `Rx`, `Ry`, and `Rz` representing rotation about the X, Y, and Z axes, respectively, and applied in `XYZ` order (i.e. first rotate around X, then Y, then Z), what is the conversion from Euler angles to axis-angle, and vice versa?**

NOTE: Ultimately I can always fall back to converting through another representation such as a quaternion, as those pairs of conversions work. However, I'd like to understand the  direct conversion.

I am aware of [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/513397/how-can-i-convert-an-axis-angle-representation-to-a-euler-angle-representation) that has been asked here previously, but the accepted solution is overly formal and I can't quite extract the simple conversion equations. The second answer converts through a rotation matrix, and, as I mentioned, I'd like to find a direct conversion.

Comment: Martin Baker assumes Euler angles are applied in the sequence y, z, x. It's strange, however, that you seem to have correct conversions between Euler and quaternions but _not_ Euler and axis-angle, since the steps for each conversion are almost the same.

Comment: @DavidK: I saw his convention was YZX, which is why I think it may be an ordering issue. I can't seem to determine the correct adjustments. The reason I have working Euler/Quaternion conversions is because I used [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conversion_between_quaternions_and_Euler_angles) as my source for that pair. Similarly I used [this site](http://nghiaho.com/?page_id=846) for Euler/Rotation Matrices. Martin Baker seems to be the only resource for direct Euler/Axis-Angle conversion equations though

Comment: Same problem trying to understand Baker's site, which defaults to XZY rotation order (where Y is applied first). I even tried all the possible combinations of axis flipping, and figure out what was the right order, but I couldn't get it working for all the possible orders. For reference, here's the brute-force search: [Javascript commit](https://github.com/endavid/webGL-modelViewer/commit/1ed884d48893712d8e6765681184ea14f2398d0e) -- In the end I gave up and used matrices. You can see that conversion in [Three.js src](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/dev/src/math/Euler.js)

Comment: Another good resource is this [3D Rotation Converter site](https://www.andre-gaschler.com/rotationconverter/), that uses the Three.js library under the hood. I used it to generate unit tests for my code.

Comment: Does it HAVE to be Euler angles, or do you just want 3 rotational angles?  Euler angles have an order applied, Log quaternions turn directly from X/Y/Z to angle, axis of rotation normal.  I've been working on log quaternion rotations with https://github.com/d3x0r/stfrphysics; which has some links to live demos (all in JS and three.js actually)